# Problem with simple while loop in python (indentation)

Tags: python, indentation

```
while 1 == 1:                          line(1)
    x = 1                              line(2)
    print(x)                           line(3)
        x = x + 10                     line(4)
```

I started using python today and I learned that it doesn't use brackets {} like java to close a loop, but it uses indentation for it.

The code above runs only if I delete line(4). How should I modify the code so it runs with the last line? I used the the formatting from netbeans and still doesn't run.

How indentation works in python? I find it very weird that it doesn't use brackets.

Comment: the syntax is not correct, `x = x+10`must be in the same tab as `print(x)`

Comment: If your not familiar with indentation you can alwais use ```from __future__ import braces``` at the beginning of your code for some help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just compare syntax difference below between javascript and python.

**javascript:**

```
function foo() {
    for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

**python**

```
def foo():
    for i in range(10):
        print i
```

In your case

**your code**

```
while 1 == 1:                          
    x = 1                           
    print(x)                           
        x = x + 10
```

**equivalent javascript code**

```
while(1==1){
var x=1;
console.log(x) {  
     x = x + 10 ;
     }
}
```

which doesn't make sense. It should be

```
while(1==1){
var x=1;
console.log(x);
x = x + 10 
}
```

equivalent python code

```
while 1 == 1:                          
    x = 1                           
    print(x)                           
    x = x + 10
```

I just tried to correct your indentation problem but actually above code is invalid if you are looking for increment because x=1 assignment is inside loop which mean print(x) always prints 1

Corrected Code

```
x = 1 
while 1 == 1:
    print(x)
    x = x + 10
```

Comment: Yeah, it's ignoring the x = x + 10 and printing just one's. I want to increment my variable x, 10 by 10.

Answer (score 2):

> How indentation works in python? I find it very weird that it doesn't use brackets.

Think like `{` = indent, `}` = outdent, but you can't have random blocks "just because" - each such block needs a control structure to introduce it. Thus, your code would be written like this in a brackety language:

```
while (1 == 1) {
    x = 1
    print(x)
    ???? {
        x = x + 10
    }
}
```

The block of `x = x + 10` does not correspond to any control structure, and thus should not be indented more than `print(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
while 1 == 1:                          line(1)
    x = 1                              line(2)
    print(x)                           line(3)
    x = x + 10                         line(4)
```

Java equivalent ->

```
while (1 == 1)                         
{
    x = 1                              
    System.out.println(x)                
    x = x + 10                         
}
```

Everything indented on the same indentation is treated like brackets in Java. 
Indentation is very important in Python compared to Java where you can have different lines of codes with different indentation.

Comment: It's just printing one's. it completes ignores the x = x + 10

Comment: @uditkanotra We know, it's just an example.

Comment: @uditkanotra yeah, "while 1 == 1" resolves to true all the time so it'll result in an infinite loop

Comment: @Pinteco because x is set back to 1 on every iteration, so technically "x = x + 10" is not ignored. if you want to add 10 to x on every iteration, you need to define x outside the loop

Answer (score 1):

python doesn't use brackets to declare a scope. it uses tabs instead.
you just need to put your statements in the same tab.

correct code is:

```
while 1 == 1:
    x = 1
    print(x)
    x = x + 10
```